# Positive word describing something that is not high-tech?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The company where I work has developed a product that is very easy to use and that doesn't need a computer or electricity to run (in contrast to competing products). Now we are looking for a word or short phrase to use in our marketing that describes this.

One alternative is "low-tech" (as the opposit of "high-tech"), but some of my co-workers find that it has a negative feeling.

"Simple" has also been voted down in other contexts, as being too negative.

We would use the word/phrase in this kind of context:

> [Product name]:
>   Low-tech, low cost, high performance!

How would you describe something that is easy to use and doesn't require electricity?

(None of us are native English speakers, so we're not sure if our feelings about words are "correct".)

Edit: Our target market are scientists, so they are used to working with complex equipment. If you are not using it yet, the "ideal" is still to use this equipment. That is why "low-tech" might feel negative. We are trying to target those that can't afford the complex equipment or are tired of the complexity.

Comment: I would suggest to those who are concerned about the negative connotation of "low-tech" that it would only bare a negative connotation to those who prefer high-tech devices.  Those who like low-tech, your target market with such a product, will not see it negatively but only positively.  You have to gear your communication to your target market.  You can't worry about the perceptions of those who won't buy it anyway.  That's why they call it a "target," so that you hone your ads to home in on that target.

Comment: *Elegant simplicity*?

Comment: I think that in the context of your advert text, "simple" works well.  People tend to prefer products that are simple, rather than "complicated", which is the antonym in this context.  Of course, this depends on your target market.

Comment: If it doesn't need electricity, then *Green* would be a good suggestion, especially as a marketing term.

Comment: I guess "foolproof" would not be apt?

Comment: My cat has never really liked computer mice (to eat *or* to play with), so I got her a [USB Pet Rock](https://www.amazon.com/ThinkGeek-USB-Pet-Rock/dp/B003DOD0TI) for Christmas. Apparently it needs to be plugged in to remain healthy - but it's really cheap to run, 'cos it doesn't use any electricity.

Comment: Does this product do something long-standing in a new way?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and advice! I'm thinking of going with "Low-tech", just have to convince my co-workers that our target customers won't think that it's negative. The problem is that the "ideal" in our market is to use the complex, high-tech equipment. (I also added some information to my question.)

Comment: *Basic*, *fundamental*.

Comment: I have a feeling that the right word or phrase is on the tip of my mind, but it won't come out.  What does it do, or can't you say?  But I do know if I need to do what it does, I want it.

Comment: no electricity, no computers.  It is purely Newtonian.  (Unless it is something in microbiology.)  It is stand-alone.  It has no external inputs.  It is presumably robust, because two major things that can go wrong aren't there.  It can be used anywhere.  It probably has a revolutionary design if all its competitors need electricity and computers.

Answer (score 3):

New Features Include:

- Down to Earth
- Back to (the) basics
- Low carbon footprint
- Innovative
- Zombie-apocalypse-ready

Order now, for our **low-tech solution** to your high-tech problem!

Answer (score 1):

The product is probably one or more of these:

- manually operated
- self-maintaining
- **affordable**
- practical
- **effective**
- low-maintenance
- trouble-free
- traditional
- **easy**

Answer (score 1):

2016? Well, here I am in 2021, a techie sequestered in a cabin in the woods to avoid the virus attack and I'm beginning to really appreciate lo-tech...

- uncomplicated
- simplified
- straightforward
- traditional
- minimalist
- honest
- humble
- understandable
- streamlined

Answer (score 0):

I feel like *low-fuss* is used in marketing material for this very purpose.  Or perhaps I'm thinking of *no-fuss*, which appears to be more common, but perhaps not as appropriate here.